# Confusion in machine learning concept for the object detection when using Aggregate Channel Features

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I have one confusion in my mind regarding the machine learning concept for the Object detection. 
The two main modules in Object detection is Proposal extraction and detection.
**For the Proposal Extraction Module:**
I want to use Aggregate Channel Features (ACF) for the proposal extraction. this algorithm needs training (positive and negative samples)and then we can do testing.
**For Object Detection Module:**
lets say I am using Convolution Neural Network.

Now my question is, Can I train the ACF first with 80% samples from the dataset, test its performance and make it ready to put in the pipeline. Then I split data set again, lets say now I choose 40% for the training the CNN architecture. This 40% dataset will first go to trained ACF to extract the proposals and these proposals are then trained according to their labels for the object detection.

Is this concept is right?